# Is it possible to include custom code into Java classes generated from an AVDL file?

Tags: java, avro

I'm generating Java classes from AVDL files for some of our domain objects.  I'd like to capitalize user names (not really, but it's a simple example) by generating or providing a custom mutator for specific fields in those classes.

AVDL:

```
protocol UserProtocol {
    record User {
        union {string, null} firstName;
    }
}
```

Current result:

```
  @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty("firstName")
  public void setFirstName(java.lang.String value) {
    this.firstName = value;
  }
```

What I want:

```
  @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty("firstName")
  public void setFirstName(java.lang.String value) {
    this.firstName = (value == null ? null : value.toUpperCase());
  }
```

I haven't found any parameters like "customMutatorBody" but man would that make my life easier.